# Chrome notifications API doesn't seem to produce any visuals

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using the chrome extensions API, I'd like to create a notification on the user's desktop, I have this:

```
     chrome.notifications.create('go ahead', {
        title: 'notification title',
        message: 'my notification message',
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: 'https://material.io/icons/static/images/icons-180x180.png'
      },
      function () {
        console.log('notification callback fired.');
      });
```

this runs without errors, and the callback is fired, but nothing is displayed. I don't see any permissions issues, but that could be part of the problem. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: iconUrl should point to a local resource.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, now it is pointing to a local resource, but still nothing is displayed. I also have already set "notifications" permission in manifest.json, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it code, its working fine.

Verify following things.

- Please add "notifications" Permissions in manifist.JSON
- check browser default settings for notification.

Comment: I have already set "notifications" permission in manifest.json, still nothing.

Comment: Make sure to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page too.

Comment: in witch script you have written this code EX:- background.js or content.js or popup.js  ?